# Remember Token not Working in Laravel Lumen

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, lumen

What I want is to clear the value of `remember_token` every time I sign out.

Here's my code in `User.php`

```
public function removeToken($token) {
    $information = $this->where('remember_token', $token)->firstOrFail();

    return $information;
}
```

And here's my `UserController.php`

```
public function signOut(Request $request, User $user) {
   $deletedToken = $user->removeToken($request->token);

   return response()->json($deletedToken);
}
```

Other `functions` inside of `User.php` that has a `$this` is working as expected, my question is why `$this` keyword return an empty object whehn I want to access the `removeToken()`?

This line of code is working as expected, it is inside of `User.php` also.

```
public function findEmail($email) {
   return $this->where('email', $email)->firstOrFail();
}
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by using `self` instead of `$this` keyword to target the `User` model.